# Create CheckboxFor MVC helper with title attribute from model description

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html-helper

I've created a text box helper to add a title (tooltip) taken from the description attribute for the field in a model:

```
 public static MvcHtmlString TextBoxForWithTitle<Tmodel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<Tmodel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<Tmodel, TProperty>> expression, object htmlAttributes = null)
    {
        var metaData = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, htmlHelper.ViewData);
        string htmlFieldName = ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression);
        string textboxText = metaData.DisplayName ?? metaData.PropertyName ?? htmlFieldName.Split('.').Last();
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(textboxText))
            return MvcHtmlString.Empty;
        var textbox = new TagBuilder("input");
        textbox.MergeAttributes(new RouteValueDictionary(htmlAttributes));
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(metaData.Description))
            textbox.Attributes.Add("title", metaData.Description);
        return MvcHtmlString.Create(textbox.ToString());
    }
```

I know the checkbox is also an 'input' type element but I have no idea how to construct a helper to use the description as a title.

```
 public static MvcHtmlString CheckBoxForWithTitle<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression, object htmlAttributes = null)
    {
        var metaData = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, htmlHelper.ViewData);
        string htmlFieldName = ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression);
        string chkboxText = metaData.DisplayName ?? metaData.PropertyName ?? htmlFieldName.Split('.').Last();
        MemberExpression memberExpression = expression.Body as MemberExpression;
        string parameterName = memberExpression.Member.Name;

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(chkboxText))
            return MvcHtmlString.Empty;
        var chkbox = new MvcHtmlString(
            string.Format(
            "<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"{0}\" id=\"{0}\" value=\"{1}\" {2} />",
            parameterName, 
        chkbox.MergeAttributes(new RouteValueDictionary(htmlAttributes));
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(metaData.Description))
            chkbox.Attributes.Add("title", metaData.Description);
        return MvcHtmlString.Create(chkbox.ToString());
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You current implementations are not taking into account model binding and `ModelState`, do not generate the attributes necessary for unobtrusive validation and can generate incorrect `id` attributes.

Make use of the existing html helper methods in your own helpers so you generate the correct html. Your `TextBoxForWithTitle()` method need only be

```
public static MvcHtmlString TextBoxForWithTitle<Tmodel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<Tmodel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<Tmodel, TProperty>> expression, object htmlAttributes = null)
{
    var metaData = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, htmlHelper.ViewData);
    IDictionary<string, object> attributes = HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes(htmlAttributes);
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(metaData.Description))
    {
        attributes.Add("title", metaData.Description);
    }
    return htmlHelper.TextBoxFor(expression, attributes);
}
```

and similarly the `CheckBoxForWithTitle()` would be the same except

```
return htmlHelper.CheckBoxFor(expression, attributes);
```

Side note: To see how the existing helpers actually work, you can view the source code [here](https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Mvc/Html/InputExtensions.cs)

Comment: Thank you Stephen!  I knew I had to circle back to the actual helper item somehow!

Answer (score 0):

I tried and it seems to work so far - still have to try a few examples where I need the ID of the element:

```
 public static MvcHtmlString CheckBoxForWithTitle<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression, object htmlAttributes = null)
    {
        var metaData = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, htmlHelper.ViewData);
        string htmlFieldName = ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression);
        string chkboxText = metaData.DisplayName ?? metaData.PropertyName ?? htmlFieldName.Split('.').Last();
        MemberExpression memberExpression = expression.Body as MemberExpression;
        string parameterName = memberExpression.Member.Name;

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(chkboxText))
            return MvcHtmlString.Empty;
        var chkbox = new TagBuilder("input");
        chkbox.Attributes.Add("type", "checkbox");
        chkbox.MergeAttributes(new RouteValueDictionary(htmlAttributes));
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(metaData.Description))
            chkbox.Attributes.Add("title", metaData.Description);
        return MvcHtmlString.Create(chkbox.ToString());
    }
```

Comment: Well, unfortunately, this does not work completely.  When a regular checkboxfor is used and I load it up with values in the model it gets checked if true, but this new one does not.  Anybody have any ideas why not?