# How do I avoid repetitive inline conditionals for defining htmlAttributes of Html.EditorFor()

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5, html-helper

I am building a form and I have to keep using an inline conditional to add a `readonly` html attribute:

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.EventDate)
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-3">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.EventDate, new
        {
            htmlAttributes = Model.IsEditorReadOnly ?
                (object)new { @class = "form-control input-lg", @type = "date", @readonly = "readonly" } :
                (object)new { @class = "form-control input-lg", @type = "date" }
        })
    </div>
</div>
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EventDate)
```

You can't use a conditional for just the `@readonly` property's value because even if it is set to null, it will be rendered out to the client as `readonly=""` and that is enough for a browser to make that field read-only.

There has to be a better way to do this than an inline conditional for every form element just to add a single attribute, right?

Comment: You could create you own HtmlHelper extension method - say `@Html.ReadOnlyEditorFor(expression, htmlAttributes, isReadonly = true)` where the attribute is added depending on the value of the `isReadonly` parameter

Comment: @StephenMuecke how would I modify the htmlAttributes object inside that helper to add/remove the `@readonly` property?

Comment: Refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30127866/create-checkboxfor-mvc-helper-with-title-attribute-from-model-description/30135407#30135407) for an example

Comment: @StephenMuecke thanks, that gets me part of the way there, however, some information appears to have gotten lost along the way. Here is the extension method that I created: https://gist.github.com/dieseltravis/99c31d22766b75f52a9e and compare its razor vs the html output.

Comment: Because your using the `EditorFor()`method, you will need to use `return html.EditorFor(expression, new { htmlAttributes = attributes });` inside the extension method

Comment: In addition, in the view it should only be `@Html.ReadOnlyEditorFor(m => m.EventDate, new { @class = "form-control input-lg", @type = "date"  }, Model.IsEditorReadOnly)` (you don't need the `new { htmlAttributes =`)

Comment: @StephenMuecke ah ok, that does work for passing the htmlAttributes (I've updated the gist), however, the Model's meta data for that property does not get passed through. Do I have to manually specify the `<TModel>`?

Comment: That's odd, you passing the expression so it should generate the `data-val` attributes (its generating other attributes from the `ModelMetadata` such as the `name` and `value` attributes). Unfortunately I only have MVC-4 on this machine so can't test until later. What happens if you use `return html.TextBoxFor(expression, attributes);`?

Comment: that gives me `<input class="form-control input-lg" id="EventDate" name="EventDate" type="date" value="8/1/2015 12:00:00 AM" />`, thanks for your help so far though, I'm closer than I was

Comment: Got it :), It because you have both controls for `EventDate` in your view. Comment out the first one (or better reverse their order to understand) - I' ll add a link to another answer I gave explaining this behavior when I find it

Comment: LOL, oh man. that is funny. I never would've even thought to try that. Works great now.

Comment: Refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29047930/html-checkboxfor-generates-client-side-validation-attributes-while-html-check/29048385#29048385) for a bit more explanation of why the `data-val` attributes are not rendered for the second control

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to [Steven Muecke](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3559349/stephen-muecke) for all the assistance (give him all your up-votes above in the comments and at his [linked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30127866/create-checkboxfor-mvc-helper-with-title-attribute-from-model-description/30135407#30135407) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29047930/html-checkboxfor-generates-client-side-validation-attributes-while-html-check/29048385#29048385)). Here's [the solution](https://gist.github.com/dieseltravis/99c31d22766b75f52a9e).

For a model with this property:

```
[Display(Name = "Event Date")]
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MM-dd-yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
[Range(typeof(DateTime), "01-01-2010", "12-31-2030")]
public DateTime? EventDate { get; set; }
```

Create this extension method:

```
public static IHtmlString ReadOnlyEditorFor<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> html, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression, object
htmlAttributes = null, bool isReadOnly = false)
{
    IDictionary<string, object> attributes = HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes(htmlAttributes);
    if (isReadOnly)
    {
        attributes.Add("readonly", "readonly");
    }

    return html.EditorFor(expression, new { htmlAttributes = attributes });
}
```

And then use it in the view like this:

```
@Html.ReadOnlyEditorFor(model => model.EventDate, 
    new { @class = "form-control input-lg", @type = "date" }, 
    Model.IsEditorReadOnly)
```

And all of the model's property's meta data will appear for the *first* instance that it is called on the page. The resulting html will look like this:

```
<input class="form-control input-lg text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-date="The field Event Date must be a date." data-val-range="The field Event Date must be between 1/1/2010 12:00:00 AM and 12/31/2030 12:00:00 AM." data-val-range-max="12/31/2030 00:00:00" data-val-range-min="01/01/2010 00:00:00" id="EventDate" name="EventDate" type="date" value="08-01-2015" />
```